# How to embed mat-icon svg icon source in Angular module (no extra Http request)

Tags: angular, svg, material-design, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material's [MatIconRegistry](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api) to create my own SVG `mat-icon`

```
this.iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('cat',   
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/images/animals/cat.svg'));
```

This works great, except that it creates an HTTP Request to load the icon. Since this is a very small and important cat icon I want to embed it in the module so no HTTP Request is needed.

Answer (score 6):

Eventually managed to figure it out, using the `svg-inline-loader`.

```
declare let require: any;  

 ...

this.iconRegistry.addSvgIconLiteral('cat', this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
                  require('!svg-inline-loader!src/assets/animals/cat.svg')));
```

The embedded file can be verified by viewing source of `main.js` or your module file and it will be embedded.

At first I was reluctant to persue using a loader because I'm still somewhat confused about how that all works with the CLI and webpack - and also I thought to myself 'this is just a file! why not just load the damn thing and embed it'.

After finding `svg-inline-loader` it seems that it removes the 'crust' from the svg which is a slightly grotesque term for the unnecessary code that something like Illustrator might add.

For the rest of the boilerplate see [How to Use Custom SVG Icons in Angular Material](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-svg-icons-angular-material/).

--

Footnote: I did one stupid thing which completely threw me off for a while. I tried to create an array of icons and iterate through them in order to import them all.

```
require('!svg-inline-loader!src/assets/animals/' + name + '.svg');
```

That is NOT going to work. The require statement is processed at compile time with some webpack magic and I don't even know exactly what the compiler makes of this but it can't possibly embed the file. I needed to duplicate the above addSvgIconLiteral for every icon I wanted to embed.

Comment: Dynamic `require` in Webpack works via [context](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/context) -- a bit of magic is applied to figure out what files that expression *might* include, then a `context` is built that includes all the files and a method for accessing them by path / filename. I haven't actually tried making Webpack handle this intelligently using e.g. `['cat', 'dog', 'tree'].map(x => require('path-to-assets/' + x + '.svg'))` but the docs make it sound like that should work.

Comment: I’m using Angular and they like to hide most of the webpack stuff away from us (which I’m fine with!). Didn’t know it was this clever though :)