# Angular loading icon from material Registery is not preloaded

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I have registered some svg's in app.component

```
public static MAT_ICONS_TO_REGISTOR: { name: string, url: string }[] = [
    {name: 'broom', url: '../assets/imgs/broom.svg'},
    {name: 'sources-icon', url: '../assets/imgs/camera_in.svg'}
 ];  



AppComponent.MAT_ICONS_TO_REGISTOR.forEach(icon => {
      this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(icon.name,
        this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(icon.url));
    });
```

But its not loaded on component init when *ngIf exists, ex:

```
  <div *ngIf="!isApproval">
            <mat-icon  svgIcon="broom"
                      (click)="onResubmitAction()">
            </mat-icon>
</div>
```

In this case when the condition becomes true a get request will be sent to get the icon from assets ('http://localhost:4200/assets/imgs/broom.svg') but it should load it on component init.

Comment: The path `url: '../assets/imgs/broom.svg'` looks weird to me. Did you try `url: 'assets/imgs/broom.svg'`? And did you import `HttpClientModule`?

Comment: @JSONDerulo yes sure, what I meant if there is "*ngIf" the icons are not loaded only when the condition becomes true and if I have many icons to load it makes some delay in the screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to embed mat-icon svg icon source in Angular module (no extra Http request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50672731/how-to-embed-mat-icon-svg-icon-source-in-angular-module-no-extra-http-request)

Answer (score 1):

When using `*ngIf`, the element will not be rendered until the condition inside is true. It seems like `mat-icon` does not start a request to load a new icon until rendered, so in order to load an icon you need to render `mat-icon`. If you want your element to be not visible but still rendered, you can use the [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) attribute:

```
<div [hidden]="isApproval">
  <mat-icon svgIcon="broom"
            (click)="onResubmitAction()">
  </mat-icon>
</div>
```

`hidden` does not work when the `display` CSS property of the element to hide is overwritten at some point. So it is safer to add the following global style:

```css
[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but yeah its not a perfect solution due to security issues (div rendered and you can play with the css to show). I was investigating if I can add something to material config.